# CiviCRM 4.6 - Duplicate memberships/memberships inheriting themselves. Screenshot included

Tags: civimember

We have permissioned relationships where an Organization will own a primary membership and members will inherit this membership.

We've run into an issue where the Organizational membership will inherit its own membership and the only way to fix is to delete and re-create it. See the screenshot. Anyone experience this before?

There was a similar issue described for CiviCRM 4.3/4.4 posted on the CiviCRM forum here: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=29822.0 -- but this does not seem to relate to our issue.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that you have the Relationship setting on the Membership Type wired back to front. Can you pls provide details of the settings on the Membership Type, ie are you using Employer of, or Employee of, or something else, and please make it clear which is Contact A and Contact B in the Relationships

Comment: Hey Pete -- we initially thought this was the cause too, that's why I included the screenshot -- you can see the Organization is actually inheriting its own membership, not from someone else in the relationship.

The relationship is quite basic -- we used the default Employee of / Employer of.(and it is the only type of permissioned relationship we're using).

Comment: Hi Alex - that doesn't quite answer my question. I want the screenshot of the equivalent of this page http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/member/membershipType/add?action=update&id=1&reset=1 and to know what is set as "Relationship Type = (eg) Head of Household is". I suspect you have it set to 'employee of' and i am suggesting if so that it should be set to 'employer of'. hope that helps

Comment: Hi Pete -- understood. Are you saying there should only be one relationship selected? In the "Relationship Type" we have, "Member of" (the contact), and Organization of (the organization). Is that our mistake... we selected 2 relationships in the Membership Type.

Comment: Alex - it would be easier to answer if you supply the screenshot i ask for

Answer (score 1):

I have something like this happening with parent/child relationships.

Relationship type of the membership is defined as "Parent of" and "Partner of"

When entering children and setting relationship as child of both parents (and parents are marked as being partners of each other), they are inheriting the membership from both parents and membership is showing up twice. Would be cool if it would only inherit from the primary member.

Comment: So memberships transfer across multiple hops? Didn't know that.

Comment: I set up a new relationship to fix the problem. Primary member for and secondary member of.